# iCloud: Is it possible to use KVS for custom objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, uidocument

I am trying to wrap my head around iCloud storage. I have read through the [iCloud Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html) and some questions here on SO. Here is my scenario:

I have a class that only has an `NSMutableArray`...that collection holds my custom objects which all adhere to `NSCoding` and saving locally works perfectly. That class is MasterList and has the property masterList, brilliant - I know :-p. When I looked on how to start implementing iCloud I thought KVS would be great, since my data footprint is extremely small. When I attempted this, I kept getting:

```
[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value <my custom objects>...
```

After seeing why that was, it seems you can only store scalar and P-List types with KVS. So I moved to using `UIDocument` and am struggling with it.

**Bottom line -**

For custom objects, do you have to use `UIDocument`, or is it possible to use KVS?

and

If I must use `UIDocument`, did any of you read a tutorial that was simple in nature (maybe stored a few props and loaded them back, maybe in a sample project?) that made it click for you?

Below is my code for using KVS if that helps at all. Not production or anything, just trying to get it to work:

```
//Load it
+(MasterList *)decodeMasterList:(MasterList *)objectToDecode
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSURL *dataFile = [self pathForDocumentsFile:kFilePathAllLists];
    NSString *filePath = [dataFile path];

    objectToDecode = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];

    //First time runnign the app :-)
    if (!objectToDecode) objectToDecode = [[MasterList alloc] init];

    if ([defaults boolForKey:kIsUsingiCloud])
    {
        objectToDecode.masterList = [[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] arrayForKey:kiCloudPath] mutableCopy];

        //If we just started and nothing is there
        if (!objectToDecode.masterList)
        {
            objectToDecode.masterList  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[CustomList new], nil];
        }
    }

    return objectToDecode;
}

//Save it
+(BOOL)encodeMasterList:(MasterList *)objectToEncode
{
    @try
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defaults boolForKey:kIsUsingiCloud])
        {
            [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] setArray:objectToEncode.masterList forKey:kiCloudPath];
            [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
        }

        NSURL *dataFile = [FileSystemHelper pathForDocumentsFile:kFilePathAllLists];
        NSString *filePath = [dataFile path];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:objectToEncode toFile:filePath];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the key-value store can only hold property list types. But you mentioned the objects in your array all conform to `NSCoding`, so that's not a *major* problem. You just need to apply `NSCoding` to convert your objects to/from `NSData`, and store that.

Encode using

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myObject];
```

Decode using

```
NSData *data = // from key-value store
MyClass *myObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

**However** if you're using `UIDocument`, the key-value store is probably not the best way to go. You can also store and sync documents directly in iCloud via `NSFileManager` and `NSMetadataQuery`. Apple provides pretty good documentation on this, and it would sync the document in-place instead of requiring you to convert it back and forth. Plus of course, the key-value store has a very low total size limit while documents are only limited by the capacity of the user's iCloud account.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I did get it working by using NSData. No problem if you can't, but do you have a recommendation of an article/example soln that shows how to properly subclass UIDocument and use it store data in iCloud?

Comment: Apple's [Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good starting point for both. For more, see links in that document and [iCloud for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/).

Comment: Storing large data blobs in KVS is not recommended by Apple - and is a bad pattern for syncing. You should deconstruct the object graph to be more granular and then save as basic data types in the store.

Comment: @Ryan I don't believe the question mentioned large data blobs.

Comment: @TomHarrington my point was that a single binary representation of an entire data tree is an inappropriate use of KVS, UIDocument syncing is a better iCloud candidate for this scenario.